# WCF Streaming on service with Windows Authentication Endpoint

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service with two endpoints defined by the configuration file below:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="SyncService" behaviorConfiguration="SyncServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint name="Data" address="Data" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="windowsAuthentication" contract="ISyncService"/>
            <endpoint name="File" address="File" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpLargeMessageStream" contract="ISyncService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="windowsAuthentication" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="httpLargeMessageStream" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
            <binding name="windowsAuthentication" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""></transport>
                <message algorithmSuite="Default" clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="windowsAuthentication">
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SyncServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

I want to use windows authentication for the Data endpoint, but have recently discovered that you cannot use windows authentication for streaming over HTTP.  I removed the security element for the File endpoint, but still get the following error:

> HTTP request streaming cannot be used in conjunction with HTTP
>   authentication.  Either disable request streaming or specify anonymous
>   HTTP authentication. Parameter name: bindingElement

Is it possible to have two endpoints on the same service use different authentication methods like this?  Why can't I use windows authentication for streaming?

I have also tried what was suggested in this thread, but to no avail:

[Which authentication mode of basichhtpbinding can be used to secure a WCF Service using Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200923/which-authentication-mode-of-basichhtpbinding-can-be-used-to-secure-a-wcf-servic)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported.