# How to prevent duplicate HTTP requests with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-authentication

I'm working on an WCF-based client/server application (WCF is self-hosted, not in IIS).

The WCF service has an operation to upload a chunk of data to the server. The contract roughly looks like this:

```
void UploadChunk(int clientId, byte[] chunk);
```

We are using Windows Authentication (Kerberos/NTLM) so we cannot use streaming here.

The binding looks like this (client- and server-side):

```
new BasicHttpBinding
{   
   Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
   {
      Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
      Transport = { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows },
   },
   MaxReceivedMessageSize = 0x7fffffff,
   ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = 0x800000 },
};
```

The client talks to the service via proxy objects derived from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>`.

All of this works perfectly fine, but we observed that the WCF client sends each HTTP request twice, once without auth header and once again with the correct auth header. This is problematic because the requests will be pretty big and this behavior causes the request size to be two times the actual chunk size.

I already found out (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like) that setting  `WebRequest.PreAuthenticate` to `true` remembers the auth header and reuses it for subsequent requests.

However from what I've seen up to now WCF does not expose a mechanism to modify the WebRequest instance.

Is there any solution for this problem`?

Comment: "WCF sends each HTTP request twice" - this is incorrect. WCF is a *server*-side platform - it doesn't make any requests by itself. What client are you using? If you're using SOAP did you use the Service Reference (aka Service Proxy) or did you write your own client?

Comment: We are deriving from ClientBase<TChannel>. TChannel is the contract interface that we share between client and server assemblies (I edited the question to reflect that)

Comment: Since it is already Kerberos, collect traces to see what happened under the hood. The response message from the server should tell you why.

Comment: The WCF traces do not show duplicated requests, probably because the Kerberos handshake is done by Windows (HTTP.sys)

Comment: On a side note why do you state that you aren't using streams because you are using Windows Authentication? Windows Authentication is a transport-level security option so it should not inhibit the use of streams.

Comment: Unfortunately it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173834/wcf-streaming-on-service-with-windows-authentication-endpoint

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher Ah, my mistake I mixed up transport security (HTTPS) with transport credentials (Basic/NTLM/Kerberos) with regards to WCF streaming.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Authentication there will always be a challenge response (`401`) for your first request .

If you're in control of all clients I think the most practical solution is to implement an operation with a minimal payload.

Operation `void IsAuthenticated()` should do. For each client proxy instance you would then call `IsAuthenticated` before `UploadChunk`.

The `IsAuthenticated` request would get you over the `401` challenge response without sending the large payload but will authenticate the connection. Subsequent requests for that connection will not be challenged.

**Edit :**

The behaviour I described seems to only be applicable with IIS 8. So I took a closer look with two http.sys traces, one for an IIS hosted service and one for a self hosted service.

The IIS hosted service seems to utilize some sort of optimization with regards to authentication. The first request for the connection is authenticated using the Authenticator `Sspi Authenticator`. Subsequent requests are authenticated using the `Fast Authenticator`.

None of these events are present in the self host trace which leads me to the conclusion that self hosting is not optimized for Windows Authentication.

[http.sys - trace IIS](https://github.com/amith-za/http.sys-traces/blob/master/httptraceiis.xml)

[http.sys - trace self host](https://github.com/amith-za/http.sys-traces/blob/master/httptraceselfhost.xml)

Then I found [this blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2015/12/12/wcf-suppress-multiple-401s-in-windows-authentication/) that proposes a solution using **NTLM**, a custom binding and the `unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication` setting for the HTTP transport. If you're willing to only use **NTLM** and the security concerns highlighted in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.unsafeconnectionntlmauthentication(v=vs.110).aspx) are not a concern **this seems to provide the behaviour you're looking for** as per the http.sys trace.

[http.sys trace - self host with custom binding](https://github.com/amith-za/http.sys-traces/blob/master/httptracecustombinding.xml)

For the server use binding

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

For your client you can use a regular basicHttpBinding with Ntlm security:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITest">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: We're actually issuing several small (authenticated) requests before the big one. But although the TCP connection keeps alive each and every request is challenged. This is obviously due to the behavior described in https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like.

Comment: Apologies I didn't see the mention of the self host. I did a bit more digging and I've updated the answer with my findings and a solution. If you're willing to accept the constraints that is.

Comment: Thanks for the deep analysis. Switching to NTLM (only) is no option for us for security reasons. I'm just wondering which magic happens in IIS that makes it possible there and cannot be done in a self-hosted setup...

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher if you're using Kerberos or NTLM, why not just NTLM? Are you making use of Constrained Delegation for some consumers of the service?

Comment: We want to default to Kerberos for security and performance reasons. We're only using impersonation, delegation is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttWebRequest to call WCF service, creating full SOAP message manually. That will allow to set PreAuthenticate to true. Make first call with no payload, Authenticate(). Then make request with payload.

Comment: That's not an option, we need serialization and error handling/propagation from the WCF client stack